# output data to excel with sheet name contains space

Tags: sas

```
data _null_;
    call symputx('ts','a b');
run;

proc export data=have
    outfile='path\file.xlsx';
    sheet="&ts.";
run;
```

But this will create a sheet named `a_b`(the original space is replaced by `_`.

How could this happen?

Comment: That is where the underscore was invented for @W_ee, to reduce the temptation of putting white space into file names, variable names and so forth. Everybody agreed on that till Microsoft spoiled us with allowing blanks, dashes etcetera where they should not be.

Comment: By the way `data _null_;
    call symputx('ts','a b');
run;` is equivalent to `let ts = a b;`

Comment: @DirkHorsten But a sheet name with blanks is possible in excel.

Comment: Yeah, it is, and users like it, :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's related to how things work in SAS's `proc export`.  What it's doing behind the scenes is creating a `libname`, and then creating a dataset.  Under normal (`validmemname=compat`) rules, you may not have spaces in dataset names.  There is an option (`validmemname=extend`) to tell SAS to allow spaces (Which you then use a `named literal` to access, namely, `"a b"n` (the n tells SAS it's a name), but it seems proc export (and libname itself) doesn't listen to that.

However, in the present day, there is a workaround for this: You can use `dbms=xlsx` in the export if you are on SAS 9.4 TS1M1 or later.  This uses a different engine than the default `excel` (which uses Microsoft's JET engine), and it permits spaces easily.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the DBMS=XLSX option and you can include spaces in your sheet names.

```
proc export data=sashelp.class 
    outfile='class.xlsx'
    dbms=xlsx 
;
    sheet="A B";
run;
```