# SAS: PROC EXPORT adds a "_" in the Excel sheet name but the _ is not there in SAS?

Tags: sas, export-to-excel, excel-2003

I have the following SAS code that exports to an .xls-file. (NB: I need the OLD 1997-2003 format).

I specify the sheet name to be: 'PB Organization'

but when the file is created the sheet name is 'PB_Organization'

An "_" has been added. What is happening?

PS: The file contains the right columns and rows, it is just the sheet name that is wrong.

```
%let Path_Org = "\\Folder\CurrentMonth - PB Organization"; 
proc export data=pb_org2
   outfile = &Path_Org 
   dbms=xls replace;
   sheet = 'PB Organization';
run;
```

Comment: What version of SAS are you using? Do you have Excel on the machine where SAS is running? If so did you try using a different DBMS value like EXCEL that will use Excel to create the XLS file instead of trying to make it directly?  Did you try changing the setting for the VALIDMEMNAME system option?

Comment: I use SAS 9.4 BASE. I have Excel 2010.

Comment: But the challenge is that I use Access2003 to link to the xls.file, ans that is why I need the old excelformat.

Comment: I can now see that if I just open the excelfile and press save, then Access can link to it. It cannot without the manual procedure. But the excel file SAS generates is a .xls (1997-2003 version)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [output data to excel with sheet name contains space](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31472432/output-data-to-excel-with-sheet-name-contains-space)

Comment: Use DBMS = XLSX not XLS and save it as XLSX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from SAS docs:

***SHEET=sheet-name***

*identifies a particular spreadsheet in an Excel workbook. Use the SHEET= option only when you want to import an entire spreadsheet. **If the EXPORT procedure sheet-name contains special characters (such as space) SAS converts it to an underscore**.*

The space is converted to an underscore. "Employee Information" becomes "Employee_Information"

see also here http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/acpcref/63184/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a003103761.htm

Comment: You are correct, but I still have the problem with Access not accepting the file, unless I go in manually in the file and press save. Even though the file already says it is .xls (1997-2003)

Comment: If yes, please replace your code with dbms=xlsx replace;
sheet = "PB Organization"; and you won't get underscore.

Comment: I cannot use .xlsx since I'm using an old version of MS Access. :(

Comment: Can you use a CSV, that will give you a lot more flexibility.

Comment: I now tried to export to csv-format, and then link to that file from Access. That worked! By skipping the old .xls format I avoid all the problems with naming and excel version etc. So thanks for the tip.